# Value "attribute" is not a member of "Model"

Tags: java, view, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I'm learning the development flow of Play Framework following this tutorial http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaTodoList.

However I'm getting this compilation error at `index.scala.html` view:

> #### "value description is not a member of Product"

It's my Product's model:

```
package app.models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.validation.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;
 
/**
 * Product.
 */
public class Product
{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String dimensions;
    public double price;

    public static List<Product> all()
    {
        return new ArrayList<Product>();
    }

    public static void create(Product product)
    {
        return;
    }

    public static void delete(Long id)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

And here is the view's code:

```
@(products: List[Product], productForm: Form[Product])

@import helper._

@main("ezbuy") {
    <h1>@products.size() product(s)</h1>
    
    <ul>
        @for(product <- products) {
            <li>
                @product.description
                
                @form(routes.Application.deleteProduct(product.id)) {
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    
    <h2>Add a new product</h2>
    
    @form(routes.Application.newProduct()) {
        @inputText(productForm("label")) 
        
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
    }
}
```

I'm just not finding where is the problem, since I've declared the Product's list at the top of the view and it's looping using the `@for` statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried your code an there is no compilation error found. Is the view that you have posted is `index.scala.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Scala class scala.Product (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Product). Scala automatically imports all from the scala package. I think you got that class and not app.models.Product.

Use the fully qualified class name:

```
@(products: List[app.models.Product], productForm: Form[app.models.Product])
```

That error does not occur if you put Product directly into the models package, since models.* are imported by default in Scala templates of Play. So there would be no need to use the fully qualified class name.